# Computing Covariance of Integrated Brownian Motions

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have no idea on how to proceed finding:

$$cov[W(1),\int^1_0 rW(r)dr]$$

I can rewrite it as

$$cov[\int_0^1 dW(r),\int^1_0 rw(r)dr]$$

but it really leads me nowhere.

Any ideas, hints, suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $E[W(1)]=0$ and $E[\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr]=\int_{0}^{1}E[rW(r)]dr=0$. By 
the definition of covariance, 
\begin{align*}
\text{cov}[W(1),\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr]&=E[W(1)\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr]\\
&=E[\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)W(1)dr]&\text{$W(1)$ is independent of $r$}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}E[rW(r)W(1)]dr\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}r^2dr&\text{$E[W(r)W(1)]=r\wedge1$}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I have to find the variance of 

$\sigma W(1)-2\sigma\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr$

The answer should be %1/5\sigma^2%. So I calculate the variance of each term which gives me


$$var(\sigma W(1))=\sigma^2$$

$$var(2\sigma\int^{1}_{0}rW(r)dr)=\frac{8}{15}\sigma^2$$

finally twice the covariance which is 2/3$\sigma^2$

However putting all together I find the the variance is $13/15\sigma^2$

Thanks again!

Comment: $cov[\sigma W(1), 2\sigma\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr]=\frac{2}{3}\sigma^2$. Putting this together with the variances calculated above, you should have the desired answer.

Comment: I don't think the answer proposed by lizithai is correct the covariance should be 0 because covariation of those process is equal to their co-quadratic variation and the right member has finite variations.

Comment: @TheBridge But $W(1)$ and $\int_{0}^{1}rW(r)dr$ are just random variables.